# What can I do about a spot of rotten floor where I need to put in one of my toilet bolts when replacing a wax ring?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, flooring

I am replacing the wax ring on my toilet. I put one of the bolts in it's slot on the floor flange and it sunk in through the floor. The rest of the floor seems to be ok. It is in an older mobile home. Is there a simple fix for this soft spot?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "simple". Do you have easy access from below?

Answer (score 4):

Mobile home floors are almost all chipboard of some kind. If you leave this damage it's only going to get worse and possibly soon now that it's rotten in the centre. I have come across a number of mobiles like this and I always carefully cut out a square around the toilet flange, remove the rotten piece and brace the edges underneath with plywood, then replace the rotten piece with 5/8 plywood. Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it, the toilet doesn't? Is there air blowing in? If you want you can fill that 1-inch area with wood putty, but most places have big gaps under the flange anyway.

If the bolt won't stay in then you're doing it wrong anyway. You want a washer & nut on top of the flange to secure the bolt, before putting on the wax seal & toilet. I prefer the foam rubber seals nowadays & haven't had any issue at all with them.